# Android: Refresh Database from Application package Cache

Tags: android, database, caching

When my application load in mobile at that time database is store in following path:

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

I think this database is store in cache.

Now the problem is that when i update the database let's say i m adding one table and launch my application then the older version of database is not update with the newer one.So it gives me SQLException.

Is there any way to update database when i launch my application, if it's in cache?

**Edit**

Please,tell me what's wrong in my code. 
Here is my code:

```
public class DataBaseAdapter {
protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DatabaseHandler mDbHelper;

public DataBaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
}

public DataBaseAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public DataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>" + mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}



public Cursor getTestData() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT EmployeeId, Name, Email FROm Employees";

        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur != null) {
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
        return mCur;
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>" + mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
}
```

And Here is **DatabaseHandler.java** file

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String TAG = "DatabaseHandler"; // Tag just for the LogCat
                                                // window
// destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "ItemManager";// Database name
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
private final Context mContext;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    // If database not exists copy it from the assets

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!mDataBaseExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try {
            // Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
}

// Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da
// Name
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    // Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}

// Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}

// Open the database, so we can query it
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Log.v("mPath", mPath);
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    // mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
    // SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDataBase != null;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {

}
```

and in OnCreate() method in **MainActivity.java** file :

```
DataBaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DataBaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
```

**EDIT**

**Log Cat**

```
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.EmployeeActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Video: , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM Video WHERE EMPID=1
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Video: , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM Video WHERE EMPID=1
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1358)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at com.example.demo.DatabaseHandler.getAllVideos(DatabaseHandler.java:151)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at com.example.demoEmployeeActivity.setAdapter(VideoPlayActivity.java:52)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at com.example.demo.EmployeeActivity.onCreate(VideoPlayActivity.java:42)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-18 19:33:56.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i believe you have to create your own database and then adding tables. this tutorial might help http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Yes @BhanuKaushik. I am creating database in SQLite Database Browser and copy that file in Assets folder.I am done with its operations. But i am not getting updated tables means database could not update in the cache when i relaunch app and that's an issue .

Comment: Ohh... are you creating a new database in your onCreate Method. of your "MainActivity"?

Comment: can you also put ur log cat

Comment: Hey @BhanuKaushik if i am **Clear Data** manually from my android device and relaunch the app its works fine. It does not show me error. But by doing this my preferences are reset. So its not good way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39498/discussion-between-bhanu-kaushik-and-shubhangi)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to delete the database when it is upgraded so that your code can automatically re-create it. To do this, add

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
    // to simply to discard the data and start over
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_NAME);
    createDataBase();
}
```

Then, whenever you upgrade the version number, the database will be deleted and re-created.

Note: I haven't actually tested it, but this should work.